# convert array into object name and values

Tags: javascript

I am trying to place my _rows values into my object value , however i have tried running a loop but i wasnt able to get the data out , the script i used is

```
    let _columns = ["Name", "age", "phone"]
    let _rows = [[{ value: 'john' }, { value: '22' }, { value: '999' }], [{ value: 'Bob' }, { value: '21' }, { value: '222' }]]

    let res = {}
    for (let i = 0; i < _rows.length; i++) {
        for (let a = 0; a < _columns.length; a++) {
            console.log(_rows[i][a].value)
        }
        res = _columns.reduce((acc,curr)=> (acc[curr]="data",acc),{});
        console.log(res)
        res = {}
    }
```

on my console.log , it prints

[image]

The target output should be

```
{Name: 'john', age: '22', phone: '999'}
{Name: 'bob', age: '21', phone: '222'}
```

Comment: Does this help: Suppose I have an object like so: `const obj = {name: 'abc', age: '20'};`. And I need to add another `prop` / `key` to this object but the name of that prop is stored in a variable like so: `let propName = 'id';` and the corresponding value is `'0'`. Then, if one uses: `obj[propName] = '0'`, the object `obj` becomes like so: `{name: 'abc', age: '20', id: '0'}`.

Comment: @jsN00b , it needs to be dynamic , i was able to solve that part and im encountering some other issue which appending the values dynamically to object value. i have updated my question

Comment: At this point in the code: `acc[curr]="data"` the string `"data"` is being assigned to every column of every row. It is my understanding that, that is why one gets that on the `console.log`.

Answer (score 2):

you can use

- array.map to build another array from _rows
- foreach value you have to check if columns exist

  ```
  if (_columns[index]) {
  ```
- if yes add in the new object the value under column name

  ```
  res[_columns[index]] = property.value;
  ```

```js
let _columns = ["Name", "age", "phone"]
let _rows = [[{ value: 'john' }, { value: '22' }, { value: '999' }], [{ value: 'Bob' }, { value: '21' }, { value: '222' }]];

let result = _rows.map(one => {
  let res = {};
  one.forEach((property, index) => {
    if (_columns[index]) {
      res[_columns[index]] = property.value;
    }
  });
  return res;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with `reduce`, just make this small change to get the actual value instead of the hardcode string "data". You need to use the optional parameter `currentIndex` of the reduce callback, then use the index to access the row item for the value.

```js
let _columns = ["Name", "age", "phone"]
let _rows = [[{ value: 'john' }, { value: '22' }, { value: '999' }], [{ value: 'Bob' }, { value: '21' }, { value: '222' }]]

  let res = {}
  for (let i = 0; i < _rows.length; i++) {
      for (let a = 0; a < _columns.length; a++) {
          console.log(_rows[i][a].value)
      }
      res = _columns.reduce((acc,curr,index)=> (acc[curr]=_rows[i][index].value,acc),{});
      console.log(res)
      res = {}
  }
```

However, when dealing with rows and columns in your case, since the array index is important, using old-school nested for-loop might be much more clear sometimes. My experience is, when you need the array index anyway, try not to be fancy and go for regular for-loop.

```js
let _columns = ["Name", "age", "phone"]
let _rows = [[{ value: 'john' }, { value: '22' }, { value: '999' }], [{ value: 'Bob' }, { value: '21' }, { value: '222' }]]


for(let i = 0; i < _rows.length; i++)
{
  let res = {};
  for(let j = 0; j < _columns.length; j++)
  {
    res[_columns[j]] = _rows[i][j].value
  }
  console.log(res);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A double `Arry.map` will do the trick

```js
let _columns = ["Name", "age", "phone"]
let _rows = [
  [{ value: 'john' }, { value: '22' }, { value: '999' }],
  [{ value: 'Bob' }, { value: '21' }, { value: '222' }]
];
const output = _rows.map((row) => row.map((item, index) => ({ [_columns[index]]: item.value })));
console.log(output)
```